# Изменение Color_Dialog PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, color, qpalette

На просторах `stackoverflow` нашел пример с `QColorDialog` на *PyQt5*. 
Захотел добавить к себе в приложение, но я хочу вырезать из этого `color_dialog` все не нужное.

Хочу оставить **`только палитру цветов`**, по которой можно водить курсором и выбирать цвет.

Пример ниже. Как можно это сделать? Должно открываться окно только с этой палитрой.

[image: пример]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Open QColorDialog")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Background", alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(self.label)

        self.color_dialog = QtWidgets.QColorDialog(self)
        self.color_dialog.currentColorChanged.connect(self.on_currentColorChanged)
        button.clicked.connect(self.color_dialog.show)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QColor)
    def on_currentColorChanged(self, color):
        pal = self.label.palette()
        pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, color)
        self.label.setPalette(pal)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, комментарии в тексте примера.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class RgbPicker(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    # создайте вертикальный градиент цвета, похожий на `Color Shower`, 
    # используемый в QColorDialog
    colorGrads = QtGui.QLinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 0)
    colorGrads.setCoordinateMode(colorGrads.ObjectBoundingMode)
    xRatio = 1. / 6
    colorGrads.setColorAt(0, QtCore.Qt.red)
    colorGrads.setColorAt(1, QtCore.Qt.red)
    colorGrads.setColorAt(xRatio, QtCore.Qt.magenta)
    colorGrads.setColorAt(xRatio * 2, QtCore.Qt.blue)
    colorGrads.setColorAt(xRatio * 3, QtCore.Qt.cyan)
    colorGrads.setColorAt(xRatio * 4, QtCore.Qt.green)
    colorGrads.setColorAt(xRatio * 5, QtCore.Qt.yellow)

    # добавить градиент `mask` для поддержки градиентов для более светлых цветов
    maskGrad = QtGui.QLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1)
    maskGrad.setCoordinateMode(maskGrad.ObjectBoundingMode)
    maskGrad.setColorAt(0, QtCore.Qt.transparent)
    maskGrad.setColorAt(1, QtCore.Qt.white)

    # создайте перекрестный курсор, чтобы показать выбранный цвет
    cursorPath = QtGui.QPainterPath()
    cursorPath.moveTo(-10, 0)
    cursorPath.lineTo(-4, 0)
    cursorPath.moveTo(0, -10)
    cursorPath.lineTo(0, -4)
    cursorPath.moveTo(4, 0)
    cursorPath.lineTo(10, 0)
    cursorPath.moveTo(0, 4)
    cursorPath.lineTo(0, 10)
    cursorPen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 3)

    colorChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QColor)
    showCursor = False
    cursorPos = QtCore.QPoint()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setFixedSize(220, 200)
        # создать растровое изображение и закрасить его градиентами
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(pixmap)
        qp.fillRect(pixmap.rect(), self.colorGrads)
        qp.fillRect(pixmap.rect(), self.maskGrad)
        qp.end()
        self.setPixmap(pixmap)
        # QImage требуется, чтобы получить цвет определенного пикселя
        self.image = pixmap.toImage()
        self.currentColor = QtGui.QColor()

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.currentColor = color
        # вычислить координаты курсора в соответствии со значениями цвета; 
        # это основано на данных Hue/Saturation/Value цвета
        h, s, v, a = color.getHsv()
        x = (360 - h) * (self.width() - 1) / 360.
        y = (255 - s) * (self.height() - 1) / 255.
        self.cursorPos = QtCore.QPoint(x, y)
        self.showCursor = True
        self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            # установить текущий цвет и излучать сигнал colorChanged
            self.currentColor = QtGui.QColor(self.image.pixel(event.pos()))
            self.cursorPos = event.pos()
            self.showCursor = True
            self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.pos() in self.rect():
            color = QtGui.QColor(self.image.pixel(event.pos()))
            self.colorChanged.emit(color)
            if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                # если нажата левая кнопка, обновить текущий цвет
                self.currentColor = color
                self.cursorPos = event.pos()
                self.update()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        # испускать ранее выбранный цвет при выходе
        self.colorChanged.emit(self.currentColor)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        # paint the "color shower"
        QtWidgets.QLabel.paintEvent(self, event)
        if self.showCursor:
            # paint the color "cursor"
            qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
            qp.setPen(self.cursorPen)
            qp.translate(self.cursorPos)
            qp.drawPath(self.cursorPath)


class ColorPicker(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    colorChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QColor)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setGeometry(650, 100, 240, 250) 

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.rgbPicker = RgbPicker(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.rgbPicker)
        self.rgbPicker.colorChanged.connect(self.colorChanged)

        buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        layout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def getColor(self, color=None):
        if isinstance(color, QtGui.QColor):
            self.rgbPicker.setColor(color)
        # вернуть цвет, только если диалог принят
        if self.exec_():
            return self.rgbPicker.currentColor

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # получить текущий цвет фона, мы должны игнорировать picker selection
        self.color = self.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Window)
        self.colorPicker = ColorPicker(self)
        self.colorPicker.colorChanged.connect(self.setcolorChanged)
        self.colorChooser = QtWidgets.QPushButton("ColorChooser", self)
        self.colorChooser.clicked.connect(self.onColorPicker)
        self.colorChooser.move(10, 10)

    def setcolorChanged(self, color):
        # установите таблицу стилей `only` для этого класса, а не его потомков, 
        # в противном случае вы установите фон для кнопки `and` палитры цветов
        self.setStyleSheet("MainWindow { background-color:%s;}" % color.name())

    def onColorPicker(self):
        color = self.colorPicker.getColor(self.color)
        # обновлять цвет только в том случае, если диалог принят: 
        # если пользователь нажимает клавишу `Esc`, он будет игнорироваться
        if color:
            print('ok', color.getRgb())
            self.color = color
        self.setcolorChanged(self.color)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setGeometry(350, 100, 243, 253) 
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто удивительно! Буду разбирать код и для себя сделаю задание - изменить форму всего этого, чтоб выглядело покрасивее.

Comment: @imapw_ я думаю, что вам будет `Полезен ответ` по данной тематике https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084479/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-python/1084505#1084505